# How to upload a video to vimeo in react-native?

Tags: react-native, file-upload

I have a problem uploading a video to vimeo using [tus-js-client](https://github.com/tus/tus-js-client) in react-native.

I try to upload a blob file to vimeo of my video that is in my cellphone.

The URI is `this.state.uri` that is the filepath to my video, for example: `file:///data/user/Camera/e520ecbb-e226-434c-8c8d-305621622645.mp4`

This is my code:

```
var fileAsString = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(this.state.uri)
     var file = new File([fileAsString], "video.mp4");

     var upload = new tus.Upload(file, {
         endpoint: this.state.vimeoUploadLink,
         retryDelays: [0, 1000, 3000, 5000],
         metadata: {
             filename: "video.mp4",
             filetype: "video/mp4"
         },
         onError: function(error) {
             console.log("Failed because: " + error)
         },
         onProgress: function(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal) {
             var percentage = (bytesUploaded / bytesTotal * 100).toFixed(2)
             console.log(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, percentage + "%")
         },
         onSuccess: function() {
             console.log("Download %s from %s", upload.file.name, upload.url)
         }
     })
```

But I got an error:

```
unexpected response while creating upload, originated from request (response code: 405, response text: Method Not Allowed)
```

Is this the correct way to do it? What am I wrong?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?